# Rails: Fetch user information from youtube

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, youtube-api

I'm using Rails.

Can I get information about user's playlists, channels, videos if user already authenticated via Google?

Thx!

Comment: I can see lack of Research before posting the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you use Google Youtube and user was authenticated, and you need find videos or channels related to this user you should use:

[gem 'yt'](https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt)

[documentation](http://fullscreen.github.io/yt/)

It helped to me